# json fusioncharts and shell script

Tags: json, sh, fusioncharts, rrd

Hoping someone can help guide me in the right direction.

We have an open source monitoring system (Nagios) that utilizes rrdtool solution for graphs. While that's great and all I want to be able to rrdfetch or rrdexport data out via the nagios shell scripts and encode those into json to leverage a cleaner looking graphing solution such as Fusioncharts.

I'm not much of a web admin so I am fumbling through looking for the right approach. What I have experimented with:

taking two variable outputs via rrd exports and producing:

```
echo "$label"

    22:30:00
    23:00:00
    23:30:00
    00:00:00

echo "$value"
    2.47
    2.68
    3.40
    2.43
```

What is the best way to get that into a json format so a solution like fusioncharts can consume it?

I have been looking at a solution called jq , which seems promising when I test / google some examples but in all honesty it's a little over my head.

```
jq -n "{label:\"$cat1\"}"
jq -n "{value:\"$avg1\"}"

{
  "label": "22:30:00 23:00:00 23:30:00 00:00:00"
}

{
  "value": "2.47 2.68 3.40 2.43"
}
```

In jsfiddle I was trying to get the shell script to output a json format like this fusionchart example.

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
    var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'line',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '500',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        id: 'revenue-chart',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Sample avg times",
                "subCaption": "Sample avg times",
                "xAxisName": "time",
                "yAxisName": "avg",
                "theme": "fint",
                "rotateValues": "0"
            },

            "data": [{
                "label": "22:30:00",
                "value": "2.47"
            }, {
                "label": "23:00:00",
                "value": "2.68"
            }, {
                "label": "23:30:00",
                "value": "3.40"
            }, {
                "label": "00:00:00",
                "value": "2.43"
            },]
        }
    });
```

Comment: Which part specifically do you need help with?  What is your question?

Comment: In guess my main question is, what is the best was to take the two variables $label + $value and output it into a json file that fusioncharts can consume via a shell script. Sorry I realize it's a bit of an open ended question. I think fusioncharts will allow me to output this data to a json file and the chart will use that file to populate the data.

Comment: As an aside, the `echo` statements could not possibly produce multi-line strings without quoting around the variables.

Comment: That's true, I didn't copy in the quotes when I posted. I'll correct that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interpolate some values into a static piece of text, have a look at here documents.

```
cat <<HERE
  some static text here;
  $label
  some more static text;
  or even $(code to dynamically extract value) in the middle
  of some other text
HERE
```

You can easily glue together parts, too:

```
printf 'static\nheader\ntext'
jq something |
while read -r snippet; do  # reads one line from jq at a time
    printf 'stuff around %s goes here\n' "$snippet"
done
echo 'static
tail
can be multi-line string, too!'
tr ':' '\n' <<<"multi:line:string:with:$value:in:it"  # here string, bash only
```

Whether you use `cat` with a here document, or a `printf` (or just plain `echo`, or, say, `date` with a creative format string -- actually, anything which produces text on standard output) to produce the string doesn't really matter from a performance or usability point of view; use whichever feels the most natural.

Comment: Thanks tripleee, I will play around with that in a test script to see if I can get the right output.